# How to perform centralized changes on objects in an EJB environment

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm working on a project where I have to process incoming message files of different kind (xml, edifact, etc.). The project is built in jboss using EJBs for recurring tasks.

I'm not native do EJBs and the ways you use them, so I try to listen, what my colleagues say and what I read about it. One central concept, I've been told, is to keep logic out of you entities (them being only data storage objects), because the entities jar-file is included in every program using any of the services, and you do not want all those calling projects to be updated for any change in the logic, you want that on a central space.

Sounds kinda sensible to me. That is the place where I think EJBs come in to provide services that operate on the data. The problem I run into, is that my remote EJBs cannot alter any objects, because they are (of course) passed by value. Returning an altered version of the object isn't working either, because that object is already existing and referenced in different places.

How can I perform operations on objects, that modify the object in a centralized manner? I will need the same action on that object in dozens of projects. The only ways I can think of is adding a tool.jar, which defeats the purpose of EJBs and is not so different from putting the logic in the entities, or to add a camel route with jump back address which seems awfully complicated and hard to understand for code readers.

Either I misunderstand some basic principle, miss an important tool, or our design must have a serious flaw.

(To be a little more concrete: I have a Message-Entity, that has many attributes like recipient, sender, message size, ... set already. No for some kind of message, I have to do the same actions, which involve setting numerous fields in the message, and adding multiple entities, that need to be attached to the message-entity. My EJB could do all that, but the changes are lost of course, and returning the modified object does not work because of multiple references to the original message-entity).

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing the point, but the entity objects are representations of database rows - why do you not just persist the changes from your remote session beans?  The database is there precisely to provide a consistent view of state, so it's the ideal place for this.